# Buscador en Base de datos

Tags: mysql, flutter, buscador, dart

He creado un buscador en una base de datos MySQL, que funciona bien me muestra por terminal los datos al buscarlos en la base de datos, pero quiero que me los muestre por pantalla en un pequeño menú desplegable donde se pueda hacer click y que me lleve otra pestaña, pero no consigo crear el menú desplegable, quiero que se habra al modificar la barra buscadora pero no hay forma.
Esto es lo que tengo ahora mismo, los numero son solo IDs que tengo asociados a lo que busco por ejemplo busco (Pan) quiero que me salga solo el ID 25, solo consigo que lo haga por terminal pero no por pantalla, entiendo que tendré que actualizar la pantalla para mostrarlo pero al hacerlo me cargo lo que aparece en el buscador y no se como actualizar solo una parte de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que estás usando para ver como ayudarte.

Answer (score -2):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un ArrayAdapter junto con un searcheable XML.
Siguiendo este link podes encontrar un muy buen ejemplo, solo es reemplazar la fuente de datos (en el link es un content provider) por la tuya.
https://www.zoftino.com/android-search-dialog-with-search-suggestions-example

Buena suerte!

Comment: Te invito a que leas [answer]

Comment: @sergiomeza88 Gracias por la colaboración pero esta app la estoy desarrollando en Dart con Flutter no en java, hace ya tiempo que no uso java pero se como hacerlo para Android lo que estoy es usando otro lenguaje para poder hacer la app para Android y IOS. Gracias